# Detect Android device is foldable?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a project that needs to distinguish a device type at startup, so whether it's a phone, tablet or foldable. I can distinguish between phone and tablet but is there a way to detect whether an android device is a foldable?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/make-apps-fold-aware
It might give you new tools.